# Make object in glass material not look like its underwater?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

My object inside my glass dome is just a normal cube, but when I render the image, my cube looks like its underwater. Is there a way I can keep the glass dome and and have my cube look normal?

render.png[image: rendered image with current issue.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Glass Shader, try bringing the IOR closer to 1, but not all the way to 1 because that will cause you to loose the dome reflections.

**Default IOR - 1.45** - Cube is bent

[image: IOR1]

**IOR at 1.0** - too low - Cube is normal but glass shape (reflections and refraction) is completely lost.

[image: IOR2]

**IOR at 1.10** - More realistic - Glass is still visible without bending the cube noticeably. However, notice the background is refracted differently as well - you will have to find an appropriate balance that works for your project.

[image: IOR3]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your glass is just a single surface with no actual 'thickness'. This means that Blender will treat it as if it's a solid piece of glass with the cube embedded within it, which is why it appears as if the cube looks like it's in water (actually it's within solid glass).

The simplest solution is to simply add a Solidify modifier to the glass dome. This will automatically add additional faces to your mesh to make the suface have 'thickness' instead of simply being a boundary into the glass.